# How to fetch session data in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to create a login process using codeigniter framework. Form validation is working but there is a problem in session. I can't fetch username after "Welcome-".

controller : Main.php

```
<?php 
    class Main extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function login()
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }



        public function login_validation()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
            {
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $password= $this->input->post('password');
                //model 
                $this->load->model('myModel');
                if ($this->myModel->can_login($username,$password))
                {
                    $session_data =  array('username' =>  $username);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('$session_data');
                    redirect(base_url().'main/enter');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Username Or Password');
                    redirect(base_url().'main/login');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->login();
            }

        }

        function enter()
        {
            if ($this->session->userdata('username')!=' ')
            {
                echo '<h2> Welcome- '.$this->session->userdata('username').'</h2>';
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'main/logout">Logout</a>';
            }
            else
            {
                redirect(base_url().'main/login');
            }
        }

        function logout()
        {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
            redirect(base_url().'main/login');
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: First, why are you checking if `username != ' '`? It should be an **empty string** not **space**. Second, why are you assigning the session into an array? You just need a single variable.

Comment: To debug this, if you put in a var_dump($this->session->userdata()); in your enter and login methods you will see what is happening.

Comment: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Comment: @itsols, Session data is an associative array consisting of an arbitrary number of key/value pairs. `session->set_userdata()` will accept an associative array as input.

Comment: @DFriend Yes, you are right, and I'm aware of it. My point is that he doesn't need an array here. He might as well simply assign the single variable name, writing lesser code like this: `$this->session->set_userdata('UserName', $username)`.

Comment: The difference is negligible and if you want maximum efficiency then the syntax to use is `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` Using `set_userdata()` is actually the "old" way to do add data to a session though it is handy when you want to set multiple items in the `$_SESSION` array.

Answer (score 0):

### Add session library in the constructor

```
 <?php 
        class Main extends CI_Controller
        {

        public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                // Load form helper library
                $this->load->helper('form');

                // Load form validation library
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                // Load session library
                $this->load->library('session');       

                $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

                if (empty($username)) {
                    redirect('main/logout');
                }
            }
    }
```

---

Another method you can load the session library in autoload.php file

File location: application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slight code rearrangement for `enter()` that provides a better test for the user name using a tiny bit less code.

```
    function enter()
    {
        if(empty($this->session->userdata('username')))
        {
            //base_url() accepts URI segments as a string. 
            redirect(base_url('main/login')); 
        }

        // The following code will never execute if `redirect()` is called
        // because `redirect()` does not return, it calls `exit` instead. 
        // So, you do not need an `else` block
        echo '<h2> Welcome- '.$this->session->userdata('username').'</h2>';
        echo '<a href="'.base_url().'main/logout">Logout</a>';
    }
```

`empty()` will be `true` for an empty string, `NULL`, `False` and a couple of other things. In this case, you are most interested in an empty string or `NULL`. (`empty()` documentation [HERE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).)

You might want to consider adding 'trim' to your validation rules because it strips empty whitespace from the input string. That will remove the possibility of someone trying to input a username using only space characters.

Otherwise, your code should work. If it does not then it's very likely you do not have CodeIgniter sessions configured properly. There are many session setup questions answered here on Stack Overflow that will help you get it running.